# Child tab conflicting with Parent tab. Parent sees the index and loads another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**SCROLL DOWN TO UPDATE #2**

When the page loads, the Analytics tab is selected by default and I call the Analytics tab function to load the content from the server. This seems to work fine...

Now, if I were to click on that Analytics tab again, the content loads then like 1 second later the page does a refresh.

I've tried adding `return false;` statements to every JS function, also tried JQuery's `event.preventDefault();` with no luck. Not sure what is going on here, I don't think its the content coming back from the server because like i said; the page loads up fine and the content gets loaded into the `googleAnalyticsTab div`.

Any ideas on what could be causing this!?

```
<div id="googletabs" class="tabs-no-bg tabs-no-border">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="first"><a href="#googleAnalyticsTab" onclick="loadAnalyticsTab();return false;">Analytics</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#googleDFATab" onclick="loadDFATab(); return false;">DFA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#googleVoiceTab" onclick="loadVoiceTab(); return false;">Voice</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="googleAnalyticsTab">
</div>

<div id="googleDFATab">  
</div>

<div id="googleVoiceTab">  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#googletabs').tabs();

        loadAnalyticsTab()

        $('#googleAnalyticsTab').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); loadAnalyticsTab();
        });
    });

  function loadAnalyticsTab() {
       var uri = '/Admin.mvc/Admin/GoogleAPICredentialsAnalyticsTab?companyId=' + getCompanyId();
      $.ajax({
          url: uri,
          type: 'get',
          async: true,
          success: function(data) {
              $('#googleAnalyticsTab').html(data);
              return false;
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
              $('#googleAnalyticsTab').removeClass('isloaded');
              return false;
          }
      });
      return false;
  }

  function loadDFATab() {
      return false;
  }

  function loadVoiceTab() {
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

---

### UPDATE #1

After some changes to the code, i'm trying to isolate the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#googletabs").tabs({
            activate: function(event, ui) {
                //Select the correct tab and run function
                switch (ui.index) {
                    case 0:
                        //Analytics tab
                        event.preventDefault();
                        loadAnalyticsTab();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //Do nothing
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function loadAnalyticsTab() {

        return false;
    }

    function loadDFATab() {
        return false;
    }

    function loadVoiceTab() {
        return false;
    }
</script>



<div id="googletabs" class="tabs-no-bg tabs-no-border">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li><a href="#googleAnalyticsTab">Analytics</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#googleDFATab">DFA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#googleVoiceTab">Voice</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <br/>
        <div id="tab-1">
            <div id="googleAnalyticsTab">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-2">
            <div id="googleDFATab">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-3">
            <div id="googleVoiceTab">  
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

---

### **UPDATE #2**

I found the issue but its not directly related to the code i posted. The parent tab is "Google API", if I click this parent tab it loads the user control (the code posted above).

Now, the problem comes when i click on one of the child tabs, its conflicting with the parent tab's index! So if i click the 1st child tab (Analytics) its actually refreshing the page because its going to Parent TAB #1....

Would I need to bind the child to the parent tab I selected? Or restrict the parent from seeing the child? Not sure what to do here.

Comment: have you tried to rebind the click after the call?

Comment: nope, let me try that and I will let you know.

Comment: Maybe, it's the content you load through ajax causes the page to reload?

Comment: otherwise you could add a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)** to let people help you with live code :)

Comment: @Dwza Tried binding it and even removing the content that gets loaded from server, functions are completely empty now, they only return false. This is madness, its still refreshing. Look at my updated post to see the new code...

Comment: what about the fiddle ?`would be more easy to help you :)

Comment: btw i guess **ui.index** is empty

Comment: Sorry, i found the issue (still can't seem to fix it) but its not related to the code i posted. Check my updated post, UPDATE #2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the tab issue by using the tab name instead of tab indexes, for the parent tabs.

The parent page was loading a collection of tabs and for some of those tabs I had child tabs. The child tabs were conflicting with the parent tab's indexes; every time i clicked on a child tab, the index for that tab would get loaded up by the parent tab and open another page all together at the same time.

To fix it, I retrieved the tab name and using a switch block, selected the correct tab within the parent. That way when a child tab was clicked, the parent would know the name instead of a global index value.

To select the tab name I used the following:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {

      var tabName = $(ui.tab).text();

      switch (tabName) {
          case "View Templates":
              //Code here for Parent 1
              break;

          case "Google APIs":
              //Code here for Parent 2
              break;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made you a EDIT **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sS4gq/1/)**

you had some things wrong like ui.index

it was empty. you can select informations from the event so check out the fiddle :)

to debug, use console and see whats in the vars you pass like:

```
console.log(event); 
// will post the event object to the console and let you browse it

console.log(ui);
// does the same like top just with a oter var :)
```

HTML

```
<div id="googletabs" class="tabs-no-bg tabs-no-border">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li><a href="#googleAnalyticsTab">Analytics</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#googleDFATab">DFA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#googleVoiceTab">Voice</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <br/>
        <div id="tab-1">
            <div id="googleAnalyticsTab">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-2">
            <div id="googleDFATab">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-3">
            <div id="googleVoiceTab">  
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#googletabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            //Select the tabs value to work with
            var tabValue = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
            //safer is to select the tabs id :)
            var tab = event.currentTarget.id;//.split("-");
            console.log(tabValue);
            console.log(tab);
            switch (tab) {
                case "ui-id-1":
                    //Analytics tab
                    event.preventDefault();
                    loadAnalyticsTab();
                    break;
                default:
                    //Do nothing
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});

function loadAnalyticsTab() {
    alert('analytics fired!');
    return false;
}

function loadDFATab() {
    return false;
}

function loadVoiceTab() {
    return false;
}
```